# Given a number of vertices , a radius, and rotation calculate vertices' coordinates for regular polygons

Tags: geometry

So, I know half the answer to this but I don't know how to adjust it for rotation.

I believe formula the below is correct if I did not have to take into account rotation.

$r  \cos(2 \pi i / n)  = y$ coordinate for a single vertex

$r  \sin(2 \pi i / n)  = x$ coordinate for a single vertex

Where $n$ is the total number of vertices and i is the current vertex.

You would simply loop through this $n$ times increment $i$ each time.
I apologize for the word choice as I come from more of a programming background than a math one.

While this formula is great and appears to work. How would I get correct coordinates given the addition of a rotation value.

Also when you give your answer please specify whether you are telling me degrees or radians.

Comment: I edited your formulas. To write neater formulas in the future yourself, please consult this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the rotation angle to the angle you calculate with $2i\pi / n$

BTW, your x & y are the opposite of the conventional, which will reflect your polygon around the $y = x$ line, effectively rotating it.

So you want 
$$\begin{align}
x & = r \cos(\alpha + 2i\pi / n)\\
y & = r \sin(\alpha + 2i\pi / n)\\
\end{align}
$$

where $\alpha$ is the anticlockwise rotation angle in radians.